# Deleting a field from a content type deletes the view where that field has been included

Tags: views, 8

Have started to play with Drupal8 recently by trying to jump from D6 to D8, skipping D7 part. While playing, have tried to re-create a simple slideshow view, using a separate "slideshow" content type and an existed image field.

Since an upload via old image field hadn't worked, decided to delete and re-create that field **after** slideshow view was created.

But, it seems, that Drupal has deleted not only an image field from a content type, but a View, where that field were included.

Has anyone seen something like this, or is there anything wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what currently happens. Drupal informs you on the delete confirmation page that will be deleted.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2468045 is an issue that tries to improve it so that the view updates itself instead.

Comment: Thanks, mate; feels like there will be a lot more of stuff like this in D8..